# Activity transition does not work properly when device orintation is landscape

Tags: android, activity-transition

My app has two activities, for example ActivityA and ActivityB. I have created Enter/Return transitions for ActivityB in xml files. In these transitions a FloatingActionButton will slides in/out from right edge of the screen. When device orientation is portrait everything will works properly but when device orientation is landscape the FloatingActionButton wont slides in.

res/transition-v21/enter.xml:

```
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="500"
android:transitionOrdering="together">

<fade>
    <targets>
        <target android:excludeId="@android:id/statusBarBackground" />
        <target android:excludeId="@android:id/navigationBarBackground" />
    </targets>
</fade>
<slide android:slideEdge="right">
    <targets>
        <target android:targetId="@+id/fabFavorite" />
    </targets>
</slide>
```

res/transition-v21/return.xml

```
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="500"
android:transitionOrdering="together">

<fade>
    <targets>
        <target android:excludeId="@android:id/statusBarBackground" />
        <target android:excludeId="@android:id/navigationBarBackground" />
    </targets>
</fade>
<slide android:slideEdge="right">
    <targets>
        <target android:targetId="@+id/fabFavorite" />
    </targets>
</slide>
```

res/values-v21/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActivityA" parent="@style/AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActivityB" parent="@style/AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@transition/enter</item>
    <item name="android:windowReturnTransition">@transition/return</item>
</style>
```

Then I added these themes to corresponding activities in AndroidManifest.

finally in ActivityA for onClickListener:

```
ActivityOptionsCompat activityOptions =
                         ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
ActivityCompat.startActivity(this, intent, activityOptions.toBundle());
```

The result: (The FloatingActionButton does not have sliding effect when device orientation is landscape)

[image]